# NullPointerException on blank scan result

Tags: android, zxing

So i'm using zxing scanner to try and get some results and i'm trying to handle what happens if the person doesn't scan anything.
At the moment i am trying **this:**

```
String scanResult = scanningResult.getContents();
            if (scanResult.matches("")){
                    scanResult = "You didnt scan anything";
                   //I assume i need something similar to .setText?
            }
            else {
                scanResult = scanningResult.getContents();
            }
                TextView results=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.noResult);
        results.setText(scanResult);
```

But this is giving me a NullPointerException on a blank scan. But displaying results if properly scanned. Any clue why? *(This is first time i have tried to change text based off result so it may be something simple)*

Comment: NPE is pointing to `if (scanResult.matches("")){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because `scanningResult.getContents();` returns null...

Try switching:

```
if (scanResult.matches(""))
```

with:

```
if (scanResult == null)
```

Comment: Tried it with `If (scanResult.matches(null))` And thought that would be enough, but apparently not. Thanks

Comment: An object's methods are available to you only if the object isn't null. So ironically, the `.matches(null)` method would have worked only if `scanResult` wasn't null, but it would always return `false` (because it's not null). Glad I can help :)